# Installing multiple Java versions in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently trying to use a different java version for testing purposes. But I can't get the newly added java version show up in VS Code. I added it in my settings.json like this:

[image: settings.json]

But it doesn't show up as a selectable version on the "Configure Runtime for Projects" menu:

[image: Configure Runtime for Projects]

As you can see only jdk 17 is listed in the dropdown, not the jdk 14. Am I doing something wrong?

PS:

"Reinstalling" the Java version is **not** an option because it's an downloaded zip file and no installer exitst for this version.

EDIT:

The way I'm trying to do is also recomended on their [github page](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#setting-the-jdk).

UPDATE:

While trying some things I removed everything Javaisch from my environment variables. Now no JDK is listed in the drop down above. But VS Code still somehow finds my JDK-17 and runs Java programs. When I set JDK-14 as "JAVA_HOME" VS Code uses the JDK-14 version. But this is **not** my goal. I want multiple Java versions selectable in VS Code (which the menus **are** designed for) it just doesn't work.

Comment: Not that I know the solution, but it seems to dislike something about ".runtimes" part of the key. Maybe that has some explanation about why options aren't picked up properly? In your version selector, for example, it doesn't respect the name, so most likely that configuration option is ignored in favour of some other option entirely.

Comment: that's just my spelling extension for some reason not recognizing the word "runtimes" as a valid word. But thanks ; )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to work with VSCode and multiple java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957396/how-to-work-with-vscode-and-multiple-java-versions)

Comment: No, I actually read this post. But the answer talks about selecting it from the drop down shown above. (Which doesn't work). One comment is complaining about the same issue I have but never gets answered.

Comment: That's an extra comma at the end of the path for the Java 14 object. It could be that it doesn't find the jdk-14 because the json is malformed. Also, I see you are using the Unix separator "/" and have a C: drive, Windows style. If your using Windows, it wouldn't hurt to try using the right, escaped separator "\\", like `"path" : "C:\\Java\\jdk-14-Valhalla"`.

Comment: Sadly didn't change a thing

Comment: Create a batch file to switch between Java 17 and Java 14. The code should change the value of Java_Home environment variable

Comment: That's the solution proposed in Kaan's link and it's not what I'm asking for. I'm trying to find out why my (officially recommended) approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on my machine, which originally only had *Java17*, now it can choose between *Java14* and *Java8*.

[image]

So make sure you have correctly installed *Java14*, otherwise it won't show up in the dropdown options.

**Method 1:** Install other versions of Java through the Configure Java Runtime panel

[image]

**Method 2:** Download the Java version on the Internet and install it.

*I downloaded and installed Java14 here:* [java14](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk14-archive-downloads.html)

[image]

*PS:* I restore all settings to default or reinstall vscode without any settings. It recognizes all three versions of Java.

Comment: This is explicitly not an option as stated in the question. The version of java14 is dev build. It therefore does not have an installer you can download. I'm looking for a way to register a java version the same way the installer does. So that I can select it in vsCode.

Comment: Can you provide the Java14 version you are using?

Comment: It doesn't matter but here:https://jdk.java.net/valhalla/

Comment: Do you want this effect? It's like [this](https://imgur.com/tkwzAM8) on my machine. Also, doesn't the Java14 linked in the answer work for you?

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But I can't find a way to "inform" VSCode that these versions exist. You probably installed them with the installer right? And again installing release Java 14 is not an option because I am testing in the mentioned development build of java.

Comment: I didn't install it, I just downloaded the compressed package from the link you provided, unzipped it and put it in the folder shown in the figure. Maybe you can try putting the entire unzipped folder in the `C:\Program Files` directory as I did. (Because I tried to put the Java14 unzipped folder in the root directory of the `C` drive, then VS Code did not recognize it)

Comment: That could be it, because my java jdks are stored in root C because of another program failing at spaces in the jdk path. (I know 2022 and we still have spaced path issues )

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, JDKs added to settings.json do not appear in the dropdown.
If you would like to resolve this issue, please join the following Issue.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/1260

Related answer: 
[How to work with VSCode and multiple java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957396/how-to-work-with-vscode-and-multiple-java-versions#answer-77610177)